# match element in the array with aggregation

Tags: mongodb

i have mongo db collection the follwing structure

```
{
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63e37afe7a3453d5014c011b"),
    "schemaVersion" : NumberInt(1),
    "Id" : "ObjectId("63e37afe7a3453d5014c0112")",
    "Id1" : "ObjectId("63e37afe7a3453d5014c0113")",
    "Id2" : "ObjectId("63e37afe7a3453d5014c0114")",
    "collectionName" : "Country",
    "List" : [
        {
            "countryId" : NumberInt(1),
            "name" : "Afghanistan",
            
},{
            "countryId" : NumberInt(1),
            "name" : "India",
            
},
{
            "countryId" : NumberInt(1),
            "name" : "USA",
            
}
}
```

i need to match the value with id, id1, id2, collectionName and name in  the list to get country id for example if match the below value

```
    "Id" : "ObjectId("63e37afe7a3453d5014c0112")",
    "Id1" : "ObjectId("63e37afe7a3453d5014c0113")",
    "Id2" : "ObjectId("63e37afe7a3453d5014c0114")",
    "collectionName" : "Country",
    "name" : "Afghanistan",
```

i need result

```
{
            "countryId" : 1,
            "name" : "Afghanistan",
            
}
```

i tried like below

```
db.country_admin.aggregate([
    { $match: { collectionName: "Country" } },
     { $unwind : '$countryList' },
     { $project : { _id : 0, 'countryList.name' : 1, 'countryList.countryId' : 1 } }
]).pretty()
```

and i have following output

````
[
    {
        "List" : {
            "countryId" : 1.0,
            "name" : "Afghanistan"
        }
    },
    {
        "List" : {
            "countryId" : 2.0,
            "name" : "india"
        }
    },
    {
        "List" : {
            "countryId" : 3.0,
            "name" : "USA"
        }
    }]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `$filter` to avoid `$unwind` like this example:

- First `$match` by your desired condition(s).
- Then `$filter` and get the first element (as `"List.name": "Afghanistan"` is used into `$match` stage there will be at least one result).
- And output only values you want using `$project`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "Id": ObjectId("63e37afe7a3453d5014c0112"),
      "Id1": ObjectId("63e37afe7a3453d5014c0113"),
      "Id2": ObjectId("63e37afe7a3453d5014c0114"),
      "collectionName": "Country",
      "List.name": "Afghanistan",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "country": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$List",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$this.name",
                  "Afghanistan"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "countryId": "$country.countryId",
      "name": "$country.name"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rv4dZIjaj0z)

By the way, using `$unwind` is also possible and you can check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pgN8xqIbO-t)